# How to determine the type of a drive?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to figure out the device type for a particular drive. I'd like to know how to do it on Mac OS X and Linux as well, but for now if that's too much a Windows solution would suffice.

so, let's say I have a drive H. I can determine if the device is a removable drive through the Win32 API function GetDriveType(). I can find that out on Mac OS X as well.

But what I can't seem to find, in a reliable way, is the device type. Like, is it a USB Flash Drive, portable hard drive (PHD) etc.

Digging through the registries in Windows, I can't seem to find much info as well. Although I'd prefer to use some API for that if possible, I'll use the registry if required.

For now, what I'm interested in is.. is the drive a flash drive (so I can show a Usb flash drive icon in my program) or a portable hard drive (so, a PHD icon will be displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the [device class](http://www.usb.org/developers/defined_class) what you want? If so you can try [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) ([available](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/libusb-win32) for win32). Use `libusb_get_device_descriptor` function.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows it looks like `SHGetFileInfo` might do the trick. Perhaps you can call it on the root folder of a drive? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179(VS.85).aspx.

The `SH`... functions are generally the ones that Explorer uses so (assuming it works) this should give you the exact icon you see in Windows Explorer...

Comment: Thanks brone, but the thing is to determine it somehow.. so I can use custom icons. The application that I am working on is not explorer-like, but at one dialog it displays volume info. It's strange though that explorer is indeed using different icons for usb flash drive and phd, but I don't see any win32 api function to determine it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(VS.85).aspx) and [`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800830(v=VS.85).aspx).  For example, you can tell if a device is USB by specifying [`StorageDeviceProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800835(v=VS.85).aspx) and looking at the `BusType` member.  The "device type" member is also interesting.

If you don't mind forgoing XP support, there is the [Virtual Disk Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb986750(v=VS.85).aspx) which I believe provides this sort of information.

Comment: Thanks for the tips asveikau, but the quaestion is what type of usb device it is.. not whether it is on the usb interface. I have already determined if the mounted volume is indeed a usb device.
Now, looking through the invo that i get, i have things like:

VendorId: "FLASH"
ProductId: "Drive AU_USB20"

or, for a PHD:

VendorId: "SPCC"
ProductId: "PHD"

But those are (i believe) vendor specific, so they don't seem like a reliable way to determine what I am trying to find out

Answer (score 1):

Use the previously mentioned IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY control code to retrieve a [STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800835%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure. Part of the structure is a [STORAGE_BUS_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff800833%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) enum, which will tell you the bus that the drive is on (USB, 1394, RAID, ATAPI, SCSI, etc.)